# Have desktop load first after login before loading the indicators

Tags: performance

This is weird. My laptop which is newer and faster by over twice as much than my desktop, and 64-bit nonetheless VS 32-bit, seems to boot slow compared to the latter. What is even more weird is that the ***laptop*** appears to load the DE slower because it attempts to ready everything in one go. As a result, after logging in, it is stuck for how many seconds with just the GDM background (the default Ubuntu wallpaper) before it loads the desktop. Imagine a KDE splash screen after login without the splash! Not very pretty.

**I know having a lot of indicators can be one main cause, but I almost have the same indicators on my laptop and desktop, the latter just ahead by one more indicator**. I'm not saying desktop is faster on this (loading the DE) but the impression is faster because the difference is that after *logging in on the **desktop** it will very shortly load Unity interface then load the indicators* one by one. The progress can be seen on the top right portion as the indicators appear.

This is how I want it ideally. Is there a way to recreate this? Some settings under compiz, GDM/Gnome or Unity, or whatever I have to tweak to get this behaviour?

Thank you! :)

*note: As indicated above, I am on Natty with Unity

Comment: Please mark this as accepted to close the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems after several boots, like almost 2 weeks in (yes the 64-bit Ubuntu is about that old because the prev 32-bit with PAE really was too buggy) the loading process of the desktop has settled in better. The loading time has decreased and appears to be faster.

The behavior is still far from what I wanted or expected because I was used to my desktop where Unity launcher and top bar would load very shortly after log in then it will load the indicators after, not load it all at once in one go.

I am curious how two things could be so different when supposedly this is the same version I've installed except that it's 64-bit. Then even the desktop has a smoother bootsplash screen and shutdown process. I hardly see any command line text that makes everything very ugly and dirty, but on the laptop plymouth is hardly seen in the beginning and lots of "ugly" text during shutdown before plymouth takes over.